# How can I use bash to split only some elements of a text file?

Tags: bash, unix, split

I'm trying to figure out how to make a .txt file (myGeneFile.txt) of IDs and genes that looks like this:

```
Probe Set ID    Gene Symbol
1007_s_at       DDR1 /// MIR4640
1053_at RFC2
117_at  HSPA6
121_at  PAX8
1255_g_at       GUCA1A
1294_at MIR5193 /// UBA7
```

into this:

```
DDR1
MIR4640
RFC2
HSPA6
PAX8
GUCA1A
MIR5193
UBA
```

First I tried doing this:

```
cat myGeneFile.txt | tail -n +2 | awk '{split($2,a,"///"); print a[1] "\t" a[2] "\t" a[3] "\t" a[4] "\t" a[5];}' > test.txt
```

(i.e., I removed the top (header) line of the file, I tried splitting the second line along the delimiter ///, and then printing any genes that might appear)

Then, I tried doing this:

```
cat myGeneFile.txt | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $2}' | grep -o -E '\w+' > test.txt
```

(literally listing out all of the words in the second column)

I got the same output in both cases - a long list of just the first gene in each row (e.g. so MIR4640 and UBA7 were mising)

Any ideas?

---

EDIT: Thanks @CodeGnome for your help. I ended up using that code and modifying it because I discovered that my file had between 1 and 30 different gene names on each row. So, I used:

```
awk 'NR == 1 {next}                                                                                                                                    
       {                                                                                                                                               
           sub("///", "")                                                                                                                              
           print $2 }                                                                                                                                  
           { for (i=3; i<=30; i++)                                                                                                                     
             if ($i) {print $i}                                                                                                                        
       }' myGeneFile.txt > test2.txt
```

@GlenJackson also had a solution that worked really well:

```
awk 'NR>1 {for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) if ($i != "///") print $i}' file
```

Comment: You are assuming `awk` understands your definition of "columns". It doesn't. By default awk splits fields by whitespace so the line `1007_s_at       DDR1 /// MIR4640` is *four* fields not two. `1007_s_at`, `DDR1`, `///`, and `MIR4640`. If your input is tab delimited then tell `awk` to only split on tabs and your first attempt will work somewhat better.

Comment: @EtanReisner You can use sub() inside an action and awk will then see only 2-3 fields. Part of the OP's problem is that his data has a variable number of fields. I address this in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28201262/1301972) below.

Comment: @CodeGnome The variable number of fields is not a problem and I'm aware of what awk can do. Your solution is field-count specific and does not need to be.

Comment: Great! Glad you found some useful ideas in both @GlenJackman's answer and mine. There's usually more than one way to solve most problems, and it can be very helpful to see multiple approaches and to synthesize your own solution from the approaches of others. Good luck with your gene research!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My awk take:

```
awk 'NR>1 {for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) if ($i != "///") print $i}' file
```

or sed

```
sed '
    1d                   # delete the header
    s/[[:blank:]]\+/ /g  # squeeze whitespace
    s/^[^ ]\+ //         # remove the 1st word
    s| ///||g            # delete all "///" words
    s/ /\n/g             # replace spaces with newlines
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

### Use Conditional Print Statements Inside an AWK Action

The following gives the desired output by removing unwanted characters with sub(), and then using multiple print statements to create the line breaks. The second print statement is conditional, and only triggers when the third field isn't empty; this avoids creating extraneous empty lines in the output.

```
$ awk 'NR == 1 {next}
       {
           sub("///", "")
           print $2
           if ($3) {print $3}
       }' myGeneFile.txt
DDR1
MIR4640
RFC2
HSPA6
PAX8
GUCA1A
MIR5193
UBA7
```

Comment: @KM Happy to help. Don't forget to upvote all the answers that helped you, and put a checkmark next to whichever answer helped you the most to solve your problem.

Comment: Will do! For future googlers, I ended up using this code and modifying it because I discovered that my file had between 1 and 30 different gene names. So:

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
tail -n+2 tmp | sed -E 's/ +/ /' | cut -d' ' -f2- | sed 's_ */// *_\n_'
```

Here's what is happening:

1. `tail -n+2` Strip off the header
2. `sed -E 's/ +/ /'` Condense the whitespace
3. `cut -d' ' -f2-` Use cut to select all fields but the first, using a single space as the delimiter
4. `sed 's_ */// *_\n_'` Convert all `///` (and any surrounding whitespace) to a newline

You don't need the initial `cat`, it's usually better to simply pass the input file as an argument to the first command. If you want the file name in a place that is easy to change, this is a better option as it avoids the additional process (and I find it easier to change the file if it's at the end):

```
(tail -n+2 | sed -E 's/ +/ /' | cut -d' ' -f2- | sed 's_ */// *_\n_') < tmp
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This comes really close to what I'd like, but it added an 'n' in front of any genes that had previously come after a /// delimiter. So, for example, it would print nMIR4640 and nUBA7 on a new line. I also find that the gene name preceding the /// disappears, so that e.g. DDR1 no longer appears.

Comment: @KM If you want the leading `n` your sample output should include it.

Comment: Clarification: I do not want the leading n - I would like to print 'MIR4640' and 'UBA7', but when I try the code, it prints 'nMIR4640' and 'nUBA7' . I could not figure out how to print the newline without the n also creeping in. Very weird

Comment: @KM I'm not seeing that leading `n` in the output on my machine. You may want to check to make sure that during the copy/paste none of the backslashes were lost.

Answer (score 0):

Given the existing input and the modified requirement (from the comment on Morgen's answer) the following should do what you want (for any number of gene columns).

```
awk 'NR > 1 {
    p=0
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
        if ($i == "///") {
            p=1
            continue
        }
        printf "%s%s\n", p?"n":"", $i
    }
}' input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Your criteria for selecting which strings to output is not entirely clear, but here's another command that at least produces your expected output:

```
tail -n +2 myGeneFile.txt | grep -oE '\<[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*\>'
```

It basically just 1) skips the first line and 2) finds all other words (delimited by non-word characters and/or start/end of line) that consist entirely of uppercase letters or digits, with the first being a letter.